# Скошенный угол у фиксированого блока

Tags: html, css, svg

Есть макет в котором углы скошенны, вот так:

[image: скошенный угол]

Решить с помощью псевдоэлементов не выходит из-за не простого заднего фона страницы  , где `.bg-body: background-image: url(image/body_bg.png)`;

[image: мой результат]

```css
.contacts_right {
  /*.left-right-blocks;*/
  top: 570px;
  border-left: 1px solid @white;
  border-bottom: 1px solid @white;
  border-top: 1px solid @white;
  right: 0;
}

ul {
  position: absolute;
  left: -16px;
  margin-top: 45%;
  padding: 25px 0;
  /*.bg-body;*/
}

li {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 35px;
  margin-bottom: 9px;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  display: block;
  border-radius: 50px;
  background-color: #464b51;
  text-align: center;
}

i {
  padding-top: 5px;
}

li:nth-child(5) {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.top_circle,
.bottom_circle {
  left: 13px;
}

.contacts_right:before {
  border-left: 1px solid @white;
  width: 15px;
  height: 25px;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  transform: rotate(-135deg);
  left: -5px;
  top: -10px;
  /*.bg-body;*/
}

.contacts_right:after {
  border-left: 1px solid @white;
  width: 15px;
  height: 25px;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  transform: rotate(135deg);
  left: -5px;
  bottom: -10px;
  /*.bg-body;*/
}
```

```html
<div class="contacts_right">
  <ul>
    <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-facebook-f"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-phone"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-vk"></i></a></li>
    <i class="fa fa-circle-thin top_circle small_circle"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-circle-thin bottom_circle small_circle"></i>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Задача усложняется тем, что этот блок фиксирован.

Каким образом можно сделать, чтобы было красиво?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот на SVG моя лепта

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background: linear-gradient(to left, #cc0, #000);
}

.item {
  width: 220px;
  background: url();
  background-size: 100px 30px;
  position: relative;
}

.item-content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  left: 14px;
  color: #fff;
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.item-content img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 90%;
  margin: 0;
}

.item-content p {
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<div class="items">
  <div class="item">
    <div class="item-svg">
      <svg viewBox="0 0 210 297" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" preserveAspectRatio="none">
         <defs>
            <pattern id="pattern" width="100%" height="100%"             patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" >
   <image xlink:href=" https://i.stack.imgur.com/mPhgy.jpg"  x='0' y="0" width="100%" height="100%"  preserveAspectRatio="none">
  </pattern>
        </defs>
      <path d="m8.3 9.7h152l24 20 19 18v242h-196z" fill="url(#pattern)" stroke="#000" stroke-width="0"/>
    </svg>
    </div>
    <div class="item-content">
      <h4>Тут что то интересное</h4>
      <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/NxSrw.png" alt="">
      <p>Стараемся учить хоть по тихоньку но помним что SVG очень мощная технология</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Это Air ...Я бы написал прилагательные о нём но команда модераторов меня придупредила уже так что ,....

Comment: Я щас в офисе т.е на работе увидел шеф и в отмезку нажал откат....и получилось что ответ откатил я ...если хочешь правку внеси заново...он ушёл домлй

Comment: Теперь пускай Air правку вносит

Comment: Меня из за него чуть не забанили ...последнее китайское ....спс