# Обрезанная рамка

Tags: html, css, border

Как сделать рамку как на фото? Чтобы она обрывалась в одном месте и повторяла обрезанный угол? У меня есть идея только с `clip-path`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Был подобный вопрос недавно - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/947023/

Comment: @klifort не совсем то что нужно, слишком заморочено для этого=)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

К примеру если зайти на сайт этого [задания](https://twoflow3r.github.io/Funbox-Test/) и открыть DevTools и посмотреть как устроена это рамочка то становится всё ясно

Своими словами : https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/jdgEoy

Cмотрим код:

```css
.card-wrapper {
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: flex;
  width: 320px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, red 31px, #1698d9 0);
  height: 490px
}
```

```html
<div class="card-wrapper">

</div>
```

Далее мы накладываем блок со своим фоновым рисунком который перекроет родительский блок с градиентом и с именем card и потом уже вид становится таким :

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Exo 2 Thin';
  src: url(../fonts/Exo2.0-Thin.otf);
  src: url(../fonts/Exo2_0Thin.eot);
  src: url(../fonts/Exo2_0Thin.eot) format('embedded-opentype'), url(../fonts/Exo2_0Thin.woff2) format('woff2'), url(../fonts/Exo2_0Thin.woff) format('woff'), url(../fonts/Exo2_0Thin.ttf) format('truetype'), url(../fonts/Exo2_0Thin.svg#Exo2_0Thin) format('svg');
  font-weight: 100;
  font-style: normal
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0
}

body,
html {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%
}

body {
  background: url(../img/cover.jpg);
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: flex;
  height: 100%
}

.container:before {
  content: '';
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, .5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
  background-image: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, .5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
  display: block;
  height: 50%;
  left: 0;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -1
}

.container::after {
  content: '';
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, .5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
  background-image: linear-gradient(360deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, .5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
  display: block;
  height: 50%;
  left: 0;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -1
}

.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center
}

.title {
  margin-bottom: 27px;
  font-family: 'Exo 2 Thin';
  font-size: 32px;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-style: normal;
  color: #fff
}

.row {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center
}

.col {
  margin-left: 40px;
  margin-right: 40px;
  position: relative;
  max-height: 490px;
  margin-bottom: 30px
}

.card-wrapper {
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: flex;
  width: 320px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(315deg, transparent 31px, #1698d9 0);
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, transparent 31px, #1698d9 0);
  height: 490px
}

.card {
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 312px;
  height: 480px;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  z-index: 1;
  background: url(../img/card-bg.png) bottom left no-repeat, -webkit-linear-gradient(315deg, transparent 29px, #f2f2f2 0);
  background: url(../img/card-bg.png) bottom left no-repeat, linear-gradient(135deg, transparent 29px, #f2f2f2 0);
  text-align: left;
  font-weight: 400;
  border-radius: 10px;
  color: #666
}
```

```html
<div class="card-wrapper">
  <div class="card"></div>
</div>
```

Т.е по сути мы тот красный треугольник делаем прозрачным ...

Надеюсь я ответил ясно

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать очень просто)

Делаем диван округляем углы через border-radius, создаем градиент от угла через linear-gradient, что бы сделать рамочку делаем в нем такой же но поменьше

```css
.one{
   width: 100px;
   height:150px;
   border-radius: 20px;
   background: linear-gradient(135deg, transparent 35px, #FF69B4 0);
   position: absolute ;
}
.two{
   width: 90px;
   height:140px;
   border-radius: 15px;
   background: linear-gradient(135deg, transparent 33px, white 0);
   position:absolute;
   top: 5px;
  left:5px;
}
.cat{
   background-color:red;
   width: 70px;
   height:70px;
   position:absolute;
   top: 75px;
   left:-5px;
   border-radius: 0 0 0 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="one">
<div class="two">
<img class="cat" src="https://www.meme-arsenal.com/memes/d5054013f48d02a72a054bae89a15992.jpg" >
</div>
</div>
```